# Remove leading and trailing zeros from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I have a few strings like this:

```
str1 = "00001011100000";  // 10111
str2 = "00011101000000";  // 11101
...
```

I would like to strip the leading AND closing zeros from every string using regex with ONE operation.

So far, I have used two different functions, but I would like to combine them together:

```
str.replace(/^0+/,'').replace(/0+$/,'');
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can just combine both of your regex using an `OR` clause (`|`):

```
var r = '00001011100000'.replace(/^0+|0+$/g, "");
//=> "10111"
```

---

**update:** Above regex solutions replaces `0` with an empty string. To prevent this problem use this regex:

```
var repl = str.replace(/^0+(\d)|(\d)0+$/gm, '$1$2');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h2tZZE/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Assert start
- `0+`: Match one or more zeroes
- `(\d)`: Followed by a digit that is captured in capture group #1
- `|`: OR
- `(\d)`: Match a digit that is captured in capture group #2
- `0+`: Followed by one or more zeroes
- `$`: Assert end

**Replacement:**

Here we are using two back-references of the tow capturing groups:

```
$1$2
```

That basically puts digit after leading zeroes and digit before trailing zeroes back in the replacement.

Comment: I know this is a pretty old thread, but it still comes up in google search when trying to trim leading/trailing zeros.  While this works most of the time, it doesn't properly handle a value of '0'.  It just trims it out completely, while 0 is technically a valid number.

Comment: This answer really helped me. However I can't wirte these kind of values: `1.005`

Comment: well, you are incorrect,  we are talking about string, not number,  not digits

Comment: Sorry who is incorrect and for which input this didn't work?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you will always have at least one digit in the input data, you can use this pattern `/^0*(\d+?)0*$/` with `exec()` and access the single capture group.

This uses just one capture group, no alternatives (pipes), and ensures at least one digit in the output, and doesn't seek multiple matches (no `g`).

The capture group uses a lazy quantifier and the `0`s use greedy quantifiers for improved efficiency.  Start and end anchors (`^` and `$`) are used to ensure the entire string is matched.

```js
console.log('0001001000 => '+ /^0*(\d+?)0*$/.exec("00100100")[1]);

console.log('001 => ' + /^0*(\d+?)0*$/.exec("001")[1]);
console.log('100 => ' + /^0*(\d+?)0*$/.exec("100")[1]);

console.log('1 => ' + /^0*(\d+?)0*$/.exec("1")[1]);
console.log('0 => ' + /^0*(\d+?)0*$/.exec("0")[1]);

console.log('11 => ' + /^0*(\d+?)0*$/.exec("11")[1]);
console.log('00 => ' + /^0*(\d+?)0*$/.exec("00")[1]);

console.log('111 => ' + /^0*(\d+?)0*$/.exec("111")[1]);
console.log('000 => ' + /^0*(\d+?)0*$/.exec("000")[1]);
```

Or you can shift half the job to `+` to cast the string to int (this has the added benefit of stabilizing the input when there is no length) and then let `replace` handle right-side trimming.

The one-time lookbehind (`(?<=\d)`) is used to ensure a minimum output length of one. [Can I Use: Lookbehind in JS regular expressions](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind)

```js
console.log('0001001000 => ' + (+'0001001000'.replace(/(?<=\d)0*$/, "")));
console.log('[empty] => ' + (+''.replace(/(?<=\d)0*$/, "")));

console.log('001 => ' + (+'001'.replace(/(?<=\d)0*$/, "")));
console.log('100 => ' + (+'100'.replace(/(?<=\d)0*$/, "")));

console.log('1 => ' + (+'1'.replace(/(?<=\d)0*$/, "")));
console.log('0 => ' + (+'0'.replace(/(?<=\d)0*$/, "")));

console.log('11 => ' + (+'11'.replace(/(?<=\d)0*$/, "")));
console.log('00 => ' + (+'00'.replace(/(?<=\d)0*$/, "")));

console.log('111 => ' + (+'111'.replace(/(?<=\d)0*$/, "")));
console.log('000 => ' + (+'000'.replace(/(?<=\d)0*$/, "")));
```

Comment: I have upvoted your answer to neutralize a downvote. However I think downvote may be because of your use of lookbehind which is not supported in all browsers's JS engines.

Comment: Oh.  I didnt know that.  Thx