# Replace certain characters from beginning and end of string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to write a regex Replaces all 00 before and at the end of a string

```
"1203444" ---> Pass
"01212" ---> 1212
"12233434" ---> 12233434
"000000023234" ---> 23234
"34340000" -----> 3434
"00023300000" ----> 2333
```

Regex is kind of new to me.

```
"000123300".replace(/^0+/, "");   --> strips the first zeros
```

I tried numerous times to strip the last zeros to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove/ truncate leading zeros by javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276451/remove-truncate-leading-zeros-by-javascript-jquery)

Comment: How about all the zeros? `"00000000000"` --------> ???

Comment: I found answer in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295121/remove-leading-and-trailing-zeros-from-a-string

Answer (score 7):

Here is the regex you are looking for:

```js
'000123300'.replace(/^0+|0+$/g, '')
```

This will match one or many zeros (`0+`) in the start (`^0+`) or (`|`) in the end (`0+$`) of the given string, and replace all matches (`//g`) with empty strings.

Comment: Did you mean `/g`?
I don't understand why global is necessary - we are using `$`... - Please explain.
Thank you!

Comment: @iAmOren.  You could just try it.  `'000123300'.replace(/^0+|0+$/, '') //=> "123300"`.  Without the global flag, we would just replace the *first* occurrence found.

Comment: Thank you.
I did try it before asking you.
Now I get it = you explained well ("just replace the first").