# How to skipping zeros in the millisecond section by moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

#### Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/c59zsLux/1/

#### What I want to do

I want to erase the zero-filling from the millisecond section by moment.js.

Examples

0:00:00.000 → 0:0:0

0:16:55.404 → 0:16:55.404

1:00:30.100 → 1:0:30.1

1:09:01.770 → 1:9:1.77

#### Conditions

- The millisecond part has a maximum of three digits.
- I want to remove the trailing zeros from there.
- If all digits are zero, then it will not display the millisecond part.

#### My Implements

```
/**
 * タイムスタンプを整形して返す
 * 
 * @param {string|integer} ssms 秒(ss)とミリ秒(ms)で構成されたタイムスタンプ e.g. "4080.770" (01:08:00.770)
 * @return {string} showTime e.g. "1:8:0.77"
 */
function formatTimestamp(time = 0)
{
  if(time == 0){
    return "0:0:0";
  }

  var ssms = time.split(".");

  var temp_ss = ssms[0];
  var temp_ms = ssms[1] ? ssms[1] : 0;

  var m = moment.utc(temp_ss * 1000);
  var hms = m.format("H:m:s");

  var ms = removeTrailingZeros("." + temp_ms);

  ms = ms ? ms : "";

  var showTime = hms + ms; 

  return showTime;
}

/**
 * 数字文字列の末尾のゼロを除去して返す
 * 
 * [EXAMPLES]
 * 1 -> 1
 * 10 -> 10
 * 100. -> 100
 * 100.0 -> 100
 * 100.1 -> 100.1
 * 100.10 -> 100.1
 * 100.01 -> 100.01
 * 100.010 -> 100.01
 * '1.2304000' -> 1.2304
 * '1,000.000' -> 1,000
 * 
 * @param {string|integer} value 数字文字列
 * @return {string} value 末尾ゼロを除去した数字文字列
 */
function removeTrailingZeros(value)
{
  var value = value.toString()

  //console.log('Starting with:', value, value.indexOf('.'))

  // ドット(ミリ秒)を含まない場合はそのままの値を返す
  if (value.indexOf('.') === -1) {
    return value;
  }

  var cutFrom = value.length - 1;

  // ゼロの削除を末尾からドットの方向へ繰り返す
  do {
    //console.log('Checking:', value[cutFrom], cutFrom)

    if (value[cutFrom] === '0') {
      cutFrom--;
    }
  }
  while (value[cutFrom] === '0');

  // ドットの位置に来たら処理を終了する
  if (value[cutFrom] === '.') {
    cutFrom--;
  }

  return value.substr(0, cutFrom + 1);
}
```

I couldn't figure out how to do this in the moment.js options, so I implemented it from my own.

#### What I need from you all

If there is a smarter way to do this, or if it can be implemented with some option in moment.js, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: For leading zeros, do none of the [moment.js formatting options](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) meet your criteria? You should not have leading zeros there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the format of the incoming time you can directly tell momentum the format in `moment.utc()`. For example,

```
const time = moment.utc("09:08:09.100", "hh:mm:ss.S"); // Old format here.
const formattedTime = time.format("h:m:s.S"); // New format here.
console.log(formattedTime);    // 9:8:9.1
```

Reference: [moment(String, String)](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). If you have more than one incoming formats you can pass them in an array - [moment(String, String[])](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/)

In your code, though I am not sure of the incoming format. But one thing is sure that is moment is removing leading zeros for hours, minutes, and seconds. In the case of milliseconds, you can use `parseFloat` to remove the leading zeros.

```
//Everything above this remains the same.

// Remove leading zeros.
  const ms = temp_ms
    ? parseFloat("0." + temp_ms)
        .toString()
        .split(".")[1]
    : "";

  const showTime = `${hms}${ms ? "." + ms : ""}`;
  return showTime;
```

1. [Remove insignificant trailing zeros from a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3613112/7008254)
2. [Remove leading zeros using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295121/remove-leading-and-trailing-zeros-from-a-string)
3. [More ways to remove leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6676606/7008254)

You can check the code here [Codesandbox: Formatting Time using Momentum](https://codesandbox.io/s/formatting-number-lyh7u?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: The code below was a good fit for me. Thank you!